# Approximation classes for optimization problems with real values

Tags: complexity-theory, optimization, np, approximation

**Question** - Can an optimization problem $\mathcal{P}$ with a real-valued measure function $m_{\mathcal{P}}$ be in $NPO$ (please see definitions below), $APX$, etc.?

If my understanding is correct a measure function with arbitrary real values cannot be calculated in polynomial time, hence the optimization problem cannot be in $NPO$. However, Manyem (2013) uses an $NP$-optimization problem definition, where the measure function takes values in $\mathbb{R}_0^{+}$, and he notes that "when it comes to computer representation, rational numbers will be used". I wonder whether a computer representation restriction (or anything else) can be applied here, so that $\mathcal{P}$ may be in any approximation classes. Any reference is much appreciated.

--- Key definitions from Ausiello et al. (2003) ---

**Definition 1** - An optimization problem $\mathcal{P}$ is characterized by the following quadruple of objects $(I_{\mathcal{P}}, {SOL}_{\mathcal{P}}, m_{\mathcal{P}}, {goal}_{\mathcal{P}})$, where:

1. $I_{\mathcal{P}}$ is the set of instances of $\mathcal{P}$;
2. ${SOL}_{\mathcal{P}}$ is a function that associates to any input instance $x \in I_{\mathcal{P}}$ the set of feasible solutions of $x$;
3. $m_{\mathcal{P}}$ is the measure function, defined for pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x \in I_{\mathcal{P}}$ and $y \in {SOL}_{\mathcal{P}}(x)$. For every such pair $(x,y)$, $m_{\mathcal{P}}$ provides a positive integer which is the value of the feasible solution $y$;
4. ${goal}_{\mathcal{P}} \in \{ \min, \max \}$ specifies whether $\mathcal{P}$ is a maximization or a minimization problem.

Ausiello et al. (2003) makes a note at point 3 that in practice for several problems the measure function is defined to have values in $\mathbb{Q}$, and that it is equivalent with the above one.

**Definition 2** (Ausiello et al., 2003) - An optimization problem $\mathcal{P} = (I, SOL,m,goal)$ belongs to the class $NPO$ if the following holds:

1. the set of instances $I$ is recognizable in polynomial time;
2. there exists a polynomial $q$ such that, given an instance $x \in I$, for any $y \in SOL(x), |y| \leq q(|x|)$ and, besides, for any $y$ such that $|y| \leq q(|x|)$, it is decidable in polynomial time whether $y \in SOL(x)$;
3. the measure function $m$ is computable in polynomial time.

Reference:

Ausiello, G., Crescenzi, P., Gambosi, G., Kann, V., Marchetti-Spaccamela, A. and Protasi, M. (2003). Complexity and approximation: Combinatorial optimization problems andtheir approximability properties. Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg 1999. DOI: [10.1007/978-3-642-58412-1](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-58412-1).

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you need to *manually* compute $m$ and you aren't given it as an oracle?

Comment: @nirshahar Definition 2, corresponding to rational-valued optimization problems, says that $m$ has to be computable in polynomial time, which (if my understanding is correct) means it is not given by an oracle. I don't know whether there is an extension of this $NPO$ definition to real-valued problems and how it should work. Basically, that's the question here.

Comment: The problem is that when asking for values in $\mathbb{Q}$, even small values can take up a lot of space to represent. Therefore, you have to be extremely careful when doing computations there. If you allow yourself to use an oracle for $m$, or at least for a function that can compare two solutions and tell you how much better one is than the other - then you will avoid the representation problem almost altogether

Comment: Assuming that $m$ is computable in poly time is another way to avoid this problem, but I wouldn't say its the best way to do so...